# Problem Interface link down, manual recover

Tags: zabbix

Ok, I run zabbix for a cisco switch with snmp. Works fine. Now I had my notebook plugged into it and now not anymore.
So Zabbix shows me that interface link is down. And I know it is down and it's good like that. How can I get rid of the problem (without disabling the check completely).

I tried to reset the counters on the switch, clear the history of the item and disabling and enabling the trigger, no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options. You can disable the trigger completely however this will also break any other triggers with a dependency for "link down". You can do this via;

Configuration > Hosts > find the device and click 'triggers' for it > find the trigger for the port reporting the issue with the event link down > click the enabled column to the right for the entry in question, this will toggle it to disabled. You will no longer receive notifications or see the issue reported on the dashboard.

If you want to retain the other dependent triggers you can 'unlink and clear' the template from the host.

Configuration > Hosts > click the name of device in question > Templates tab > find the template in question and note its name > Click 'Unlink and clear' > Update button. Then immediately re-add it and click 'Update'. For most of my switches it is called "Template Net Network Generic Device SNMPv2" and is the only template for the switch. It will take some time before discovery re-adds all the ports again so give it some time.

You can accomplish the same thing by completely removing and re-adding the host. Both will reset stats for the device to some extent.

You could also edit the discovery rule that is auto discovering and adding all those triggers and exclude the ports you don't want to monitor for this trigger with a filter. You can check that out under;

Configuration > Hosts > Click the name of the device > Discovery rules.